# How do I import and use js static resources in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, static-resources, locker-service, community-builder

I'm trying to use a static resource in a Lightning Web Component. The component is embedded in a Sites (formerly known as Communities) Page, in case that matters

The relevant code in the static resource is:

```
(((root, factory) => () {
    root.org = root.org || {};
    root.org.cometd = factory();
})(this, () => {
    //this part is over 3k lines and not relevant
}));
```

I've verified that the above code is running as intended when I import the resource via `console.log` statements. Moreover, I've found that the value of `this`, and consequently the value of `root` is the JavaScript global `window`. So I should be able to access the value in my code via `window.org`. I have also verified that the value of `root.org` is what I expect- a usable module.

Meanwhile, my component's code looks like this:

```
import cometdlwc from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/cometd";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getSessionId) //custom apex method to get session id, working just fine
    wiredSessionId({ error, data }) {
        loadScript(this, cometdlwc).then(() => {
            console.log(window.org); //incorrectly outputting undefined
        }
    }
}
```

On further investigation, it seems that it's because the value of `window` for the resource is the actual window variable, whereas my code calling `window` gets the Lightning Locker Secure Window.

So my question is, is there a way to access the imported values in LWC? Either by having some other variable set, giving the import access to the Secure Window, or something else? Is it just a Communities issue?

Comment: Did you make a test where the `this part is over 3k lines and not relevant` has been removed? Just to make sure it is coming from the way it is loaded?

Comment: @Bartheleway I have tested that, that part is a function which is passed in as the `factory` parameter. I've checked what `factory()` does, it works exactly as intended. To be clear, that code isn't what I wrote, it's from the publicly available `cometd` module- all information about it I got from working with the code.

Comment: What I mean is making a test where the factory function is just an empty function. Just to be sure that the issue doesn't comes from the code inside the factory function as Salesforce framework may hide it.

Comment: @Bartheleway it doesn't change much. And to be clear- when I `console.log` the value of `factory()` within the static resource, I get the expected result. I just can't access it from the lwc.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. `this` in your script is the `native` window, while `window` refers to a synthetic `window` object. [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) designs typically expect `window` to be `this`, although that's not universally true. Some use `window` explicitly, and those would work without modification. Unfortunately, the code you're using doesn't do this. However, the fix is simple.

```
})(this, () => {
```

Can be changed to:

```
})(window, function() {
```

And everything should work as you expect.

Or, you can change `root.org` to `window.org` in the first few lines of code.

Comment: Just tried this, it's not resulting in the desired changes. Every way I've tried spinning it thus far, `this` and `window` both refer to the native window from the static resource, but `window` in the LWC refers to the Locker window.

Comment: To speak plainly, this solution did not work.

Comment: @SarcasticSully I saw your previous comment, but it got lost in the shuffle of life. Let me see if I can try and make it work.

Comment: @SarcasticSully Actually, have you seen the [demo version](https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api/)? Does that not work out of the box?

Comment: it does not. It hits what appears to be exactly the same problem as before- that the `window` accessed by the static resource is not the same as the lwc's `window`

Comment: I just got it to work by disabling locker service in the site.